# Listview is not showing list items in API 23

Tags: android, listview, android-6.0-marshmallow

Listview - List items shows empty text in music app, **API 23**

I turned on storage permission in emulator, app is working fine till **API 22**
I have posted [My App is not working in API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634916/my-app-is-not-working-in-api-23) in detail with screen shot, please give some suggestion to solve, 
I found nothing in net for this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My App is not working in API 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634916/my-app-is-not-working-in-api-23)

Answer (score 2):

I think the textColor is white. So you are not able to see the row items.

You can change the textcolor and everything will work fine.

Or you can change the theme or you can give your own textview's id on arrayAdapter with desired text colour

Comment: updated with code, I have tested with various colours it is updating in below API 23, but list item background and text colour for API 23 remains white.

Comment: I think you got the solution the foreground colour of your list item is near to white

Comment: yeah I got the solution.